# Result of an assignment in Java

Tags: assignment-operator

I am looking at the code on page 11 here http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/doc/java/JavaIO-notes.pdf

I have trouble with one statement. I thought the result of an assignment was an lvalue. So ((byteRead = inFile.read()) != -1) should be the same as (inFile.read()) != -1). This doesn't seem to be the case though looking at the output. So my question is how is the statement ((byteRead = inFile.read()) != -1) parsed?

EDIT: It seems from the responses that I had the current interpretation of the result of an assignment. I was wondering what goes wrong by replacing the code fragment

int byteRead;

while((byteRead = inFile.read()) != -1)

outFile.write(byteRead);

with

while( inFile.read() != -1)

outFile.write( inFile.read());

Comment: You're missing something else. Assignments work the way you correctly think they do.

Comment: Don't figure out your problem. Please be more precised.

Comment: No idea what you are asking.  what 'output' are you looking at? FYI, byteRead is assigned the value from inFile.read(), then it's compared to -1. Note that your second 'test' has too many close parens.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: The output of the program. If I use the alternate statement, the copying process does not take place as expected. I get some data in the destination file, but it is not the same as the source file even though I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now that you posted both versions of code, the answer is clear:

In your first version, each byte read is assigned to byteRead and then written to the output stream.

In the second version, you consume a byte with the read() but don't assign it to a variable. Then, you read another byte (the next one in the stream) which you write to the output stream.

So, if the input file is:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

The output of the first version will be :

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

The output of the second will be :

```
bdfhjlnqrtuxz
```

Answer (score 0):

((byteRead = inFile.read()) != -1) and (inFile.read() != -1) are, in one sense, equivalent boolean expressions. However, the first one has a side effect: It stores the result of inFile.read() in the variable byteRead.

The code example you referenced uses this for a compact while loop that reads one byte from input, writes it to output and keeps doing that until inFile.read() returns -1 (meaning end of file has been reached).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I thought. But then if I replace that code fragment by 
while( inFile.read() != -1)
outFile.write(inFile.read()); I thought I should get the same output, but I don't

Comment: Read the documentation on InputStream. Basically, every time you call read(), you get a new byte.